# Boolean wont Update from Object.getBoolean();

Tags: java, javafx, jfilechooser, filechooser

Pretty much, I'm trying to write a simple program that lets the user choose a file. Unfortunately, JFileChooser through Swing is a little outdated, so I am trying to use JavaFX FileChooser for this. The goal is to run FileGetter as a thread, transfer the file data to the Main Class, and continue from there.

Main Class:

```
package application;
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new FileGetter());
        FileGetter fg = new FileGetter();
        t1.start();
        boolean isReady = false;
        while(isReady == false){
            isReady = FileGetter.getIsReady();      
        }
        File file = FileGetter.getFile();

        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        ...

    }
}
```

FileGetter Class:

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class FileGetter extends Application implements Runnable {

    static File file;
    static boolean isReady = false;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            while(file == null){
            file = fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            }
            isReady = true;
            Platform.exit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
       launch();
    }

    public static boolean getIsReady(){
        return isReady;
    }

    public static File getFile(){
        return file;
    }

}
```

Problem is that the value of isReady in the while loop doesn't update to true when the user picked a file (the reason I have it is to prevent the code in Main from continuing with a File set to null).

Any help, alternative suggestions, or explanations as of why this happens is very much appreciated!

Comment: Make your `isReady` in FileGetter `volatile`.

Comment: @Codebender That worked! Thanks! Just curious as a side note, for some reason it worked when I included a System.out.println(isReady); in the while loop. Anyone know the reason for that?

Comment: The while loop in FileGetter#start is to ensure that the user does pick a file, whereas the while loop in the Main Class is to ensure that the code does not continue before a file is chosen. But yes I could use the same conditional statement in both, however I believe it is the same concept.

Comment: Thank you for all your help guys!

Comment: Oh, ok. I see what you're saying! Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @JonnyHenly That won't work: you *must* create the `FileChooser` on the FX Application Thread (similarly to creating a Swing `JFileChooser` on the AWT event dispatch thread), and also must ensure the FX toolkit is started first. Moving that loop to `main(...)` will throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @James_D Ohh you're right, it slipped my mind that the loop was in the FX Application Thread. Now the two while loops make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The easiest way to implement this**

Instead of trying to drive the horse with the cart, why not just follow the standard JavaFX lifecycle? In other words, make your `Main` class a subclass of `Application`, get the file in the `start()` method, and then proceed (in a background thread) with the rest of the application?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // make sure we don't exit when file chooser is closed...
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        File file = null ;
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        while(file == null){
            file = fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        }
        final File theFile = file ;
        new Thread(() -> runApplication(theFile)).start();
    }

    private void runApplication(File file) {
        // run your application here...
    }

}
```

---

**What is wrong with your code**

If you really want the `Main` class to be separate from the JavaFX `Application` class (which doesn't really make sense: once you have decided to use a JavaFX `FileChooser`, you have decided you are writing a JavaFX application, so the startup class should be a subclass of `Application`), then it gets a bit tricky. There are several issues with your code as it stands, some of which are addressed in other answers. The main issue, as shown in Fabian's answer, is that you are referencing `FileGetter.isReady` from multiple threads without ensuring liveness. This is exactly the issue addressed in Josh Bloch's [*Effective Java*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) (Item 66 in the 2nd edition).

Another issue with your code is that you won't be able to use the `FileGetter` more than once (you can't call `launch()` more than once), which might not be an issue in your code now, but almost certainly will be at some point with this application as development progresses. The problem is that you have mixed two issues: starting the FX toolkit, and retrieving a File from a `FileChooser`. The first thing must only be done once; the second should be written to be reusable.

And finally your loop

```
while(isReady == false){
    isReady = FileGetter.getIsReady();      
}
```

is very bad practice: it checks the `isReady` flag as fast as it possibly can. Under some (fairly unusual) circumstances, it could even prevent the FX Application thread from having any resources to run. This should just block until the file is ready.

---

**How to fix without making `Main` a JavaFX `Application`**

So, again only if you have a really pressing need to do so, I would first create a class that just has the responsibility of starting the FX toolkit. Something like:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXStarter extends Application {

    private static final AtomicBoolean startRequested = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    public void init() {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        latch.countDown();
    }

    /** Starts the FX toolkit, if not already started via this method,
     ** and blocks execution until it is running.
     **/
    public static void startFXIfNeeded() throws InterruptedException {
        if (! startRequested.getAndSet(true)) {
            new Thread(Application::launch).start();
        }
        latch.await();
    }
}
```

Now create a class that gets a file for you. This should ensure the FX toolkit is running, using the previous class. This implementation allows you to call `getFile()` from any thread:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;


public class FileGetter {

    /**
     ** Retrieves a file from a JavaFX File chooser. This method can 
     ** be called from any thread, and will block until the user chooses
     ** a file.
     **/

    public File getFile() throws InterruptedException {

        FXStarter.startFXIfNeeded() ;

        if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
            return doGetFile();
        } else {
            FutureTask<File> task = new FutureTask<File>(this::doGetFile);
            Platform.runLater(task);
            try {
                return task.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException exc) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exc);
            }
        }
    }

    private File doGetFile() {
        File file = null ;
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser() ;

        while (file == null) {
            file = chooser.showOpenDialog(null) ;
        }

        return file ;
    }
}
```

and finally your `Main` is just

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        File file = new FileGetter().getFile();
        // proceed...
    }
}
```

Again, this is pretty complex; I see no reason not to simply use the standard FX Application lifecycle for this, as in the very first code block in the answer.

Comment: What advantages would using your code that still has the `main` class over my code (if I update it to store the File data in my `main` class and update the boolean and File types to volatile) (not trying to discredit your code or anything, just curious on the advantages)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "update it to store the file data in my `Main` class. How would you be starting the FX toolkit?

Comment: Just create a file variable in my `main` class and store the User's file choice in there (I think you were previously referencing that I couldn't keep referencing the file through `FileGetter.getFile()` when the thread stopped, so I store it in a File variable?).

Comment: But how are you going to wait until the user chooses something, without the busy-while loop? I guess I am not understanding what you are asking; maybe show some code. And what I meant was that you wouldn't be able to ask the user for another file later, because you can't call `launch()` more than once in the same application.

Comment: Alright, I went back and reread some things you've said, and it's making much more sense now, thank you. Also, I apologize for my terrible wording with all that stuff. All I was trying to say was to create a File variable in my main class and set it to the file the user chooses. A simple `File file = FileGetter.getFile()` rather than referring to the file throughout the rest of the code as `FileGetter.getFile()`. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

The java memory model does not require variable values to be the same in different threads except under specific conditions.

What is happening here is that the `FileGetter` thread is updating the value in the own memory that is only accessed from this thread, but your main thread doesn't see the updated value, since it only sees the version of the variable stored in it's own memory that is different from the one of the `FileGetter` thread. Each of the threads has it's own copy of the field in memory, which is perfectly fine according to the java specification.

To fix this, you can simply add the `volatile` modifier to `isReady`:

```
static volatile boolean isReady = false;
```

which makes sure the updated value will be visible from your main thread.

Furthermore I recommend reducing the number of `FileGetter` instances you create. In your code 3 instances are created, but only 1 is used.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> Application.launch(FileGetter.class));
t1.start();
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In this code

```
 while(isReady == false){
        isReady = FileGetter.getIsReady();      
 }
```

there is nothing that is going to change the state of `FileGetter`'s isReady to `true`

Comment: Wait what about when `file` becomes non-null in `FileGetter#start`? I might just be missing something.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but it doesn't work for some reason... And isReady should set to true when the user picks a file from the FileChooser.

Comment: It's also a terrible busy-wait.

Comment: @JonnyHenly That all happens on a different thread. There is no guarantee as to when, or even as to *if*, the current thread will see the change made to `isReady` on a different thread. See fabian's answer, and [*Effective Java*, 2nd edition, Item 66](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683).